# contenteditable: trigger event on image resize when using handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

Just in firefox i want to trigger an event whenever the size of an image is changed.

When you click an image in a contenteditable area firefox gives it handles and you can adjust the size, as soon as the mouseup is done i want to trigger an event so i can get some information from the image, the rest is easy, i just cant find something that fires off when the handle is dragged and let go on the image.

Im guessing something in jquery could monitor the div using the live function.

Comment: Can't you just bind a `mouseup` handler to the DIV or image?

Comment: no, this doesnt work, doesnt seem ro register any type of click if you drag the handles of an editable image

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may observe the [DOMAttrModified](http://help.dottoro.com/ljdchxcl.php)-event:

```
editableDivNode
  .addEventListener ('DOMAttrModified', 
                      function(e)
                      {
                        if(e.target.tagName=='IMG'
                            && e.target.getAttribute('_moz_resizing')  
                              && e.attrName=='style' 
                                && e.newValue.match(/width|height/))
                        {
                          //do something here but don't prompt the user
                        }
                      }, 
                      false);
```